# Colorize and disassemble byte sequences with IDA Pro and IDAPython

Tags: ida, disassembly, idapython, binary

Maybe someone could help me with the following problem:

I have an interesting byte sequence that I found within a MIPS ELF binary that exists on the hard drive. This byte sequence may be, for example, `9c 6c 3c 04 80 2d 24 84 85`. Now I want to find this byte sequence with IDAPython. Therefore, I use the `idc.FindBinary()` function like so:

```
address = idc.FindBinary(0, SEARCH_DOWN, byte_sequence)
```

which finds the first occurrence of the byte sequence at `address`. In general I want to achieve two things:

1. I want to colorize the effected affected lines in the IDA View
2. I want to get the disassembled instructions

Currently there are two subproblems I want to solve:

1. The byte sequence may start **within** the instruction, for example, in a `jal address` the byte sequence starts at `address` instead of at `jal`. **How can I search backwards to find the beginning of the instruction when the byte sequence started within the instruction?** Colorizing works with:

   ```
   SetColor(address, CIC_ITEM, 0x208020)
   ```
2. If the byte sequence is 9 bytes long (as in the example above), **how can I tell IDAPython to disassemble all 9 bytes**. I would have to know how "long" the instructions are that IDAPython disassembles to get to the next instruction. What I know is that I can disassemble at a single addresses with:

   ```
   disasm = idc.GetDisasm(address)
   ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not 100% sure, but i seem to remember that MIPS instructions are always exactly 4 bytes, so you can just do some modulo calculations. Otherwise, [PrevHead](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/265.shtml) and [NextHead](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/264.shtml) are probably what you want (`idc.PrevHead` and `idc.NextHead` in [IdaPython](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do that using Sark:

```
# Get all the lines relevant to your bytes
for line in sark.lines(start=address, end=address + len(byte_sequence)):
    # For each line, color it, and print the disasm and the instruction length
    line.color = 0x123456
    print 'Line Size: {}\nLine Disasm: {}'.format(line.size, line.disasm)
```

You might need to add handling for cases where there is no disassembly (the bytes are data-bytes and not code).